# Virtuoso decimal separator

Tags: virtuoso

I have some `.ttl` files with doubles and floats with `.` (point) as the decimal separator.

Is possible to change the decimal separator to a `,` (comma) when loading to  [OpenLink Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) v07.20.3213?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Turtle](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/) relies on [XML Schema Datatypes](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-primitive-datatypes), in which the only valid decimal separator is the dot.

Subsequent (re)presentation of these values may vary based on locale (which may change the decimal separator to comma and/or add a thousands separator), but that seems like a different question...

(Note that v07.20.3213 is rather elderly, as of this writing; updating to current v7.20.3217 or later is recommended for all users, whether [Open Source](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VOSNews) or [Commercial](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/download/) Edition.)

(ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)

Comment: So you recommend insert the decimal data into Virtusoso with points and focus on the representation of another program?

Comment: I think that neither Turtle's nor Virtuoso's internal representation actually matter here.  When you get data *out* of Virtuoso, the serialization or tool used may force the dot (as with `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` in Turtle) or allow some locale-based adjustment (as with any `STRING` and many tools' visible representations of numerics).

Answer (score 0):

If a CSV file structure differs from the default CSV file settings, the loader will look for a configuration file of the same name as the CSV file with a `.cfg` filename extension. This file should contain parameters similar to those below, indicating the CSV file's structure:

```
[csv]
csv-delimiter=<delimiter char>
csv-quote=<quote char>
header=<zero based header offset>
offset=<zero based data offset>
```

- Invisible "tab" and "space" delimiters should be specified by those names, without the quotation marks.
- Other delimiter characters (comma, period, etc.) should simply be typed in.
- "Smart" quotation marks which differ at start and end (including but not limited to `« »`, `‹ ›`, `“ ”`, and `‘ ’`) are not currently supported.

**Example**

Consider loading a gzipped CSV file, `csv-example.csv.gz`, with the non-default CSV structure below:

```
'Southern North Island wood availability forecast for the period
2008-2040'       'Table 14: Wood availability and average clearfell age
for other species in Eastern Southern North Island'      'Year
ending' 'Recoverable volume'    'Average age' 'December'    '(000 m3
i.b.)'  '(years)' 2006  0   0 2007  0   0 2008  48  49 2009 45  46
...
```

In this example

- the header is on the third line, #2 with a zero-base
- the data starts from the fifth line, #4 with a zero-base
- the delimiter is tab
- the quote char is the single-quote, or apostrophe

Loading this file requires the creation of a configuration file, `csv-example.cfg`, containing the entries:

```
[csv]
csv-delimiter=tab
csv-quote='
header=2
offset=4
```

[More Info..](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtCsvFileBulkLoader)

Comment: Thanks @Techidiot, but i,m using rdf Turtle files (ttl extension). Is there a similar way with those ones?